# Jquery drop down selection

Tags: jquery

How can use the the drop down box to show different forms based on user selections in  the dropdown using jQuery?

Comment: i get that you want to populate drop down box  but what do you mean by `show different forms `

Comment: your question is too vague, please show some code example for us to help you with

Comment: The drop down box is already populated . its simple drop down box  based on the user selection of  a value .  a form will appear underneath. For each value in the drop down box  a..differnt forms will appear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor the `change` event of a select list. Based on the value chosen hide or show a form.

http://jsfiddle.net/84dNc/

```
/* use classes to maximize performance when hiding/showing */
form  { display: none; height: 100px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid gray;}
form.active { display: block; }

$('select').change( function() {
    $('form.' + $(this).val()).addClass('active').siblings('form').removeClass('active');     
});
```

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>    
</select>

<form class="a">
    Form A
</form>

<form class="b">
    Form B
</form>

<form class="c">
    Form C
</form>
```